# how to use a integer variable inside SQL INSERT

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Cannot insert a variable using INSERT in MS ACCESS.

the insert works great when I insert a hard-coded value such as

```
 dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
                 & "(FlightID) VALUES " _
                 & "('2');"
```

But fails with a variable

```
Private Sub MainSaveBtn_Click()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim id As Integer

    id = 20
    Debug.Print id
    dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
                 & "(FlightID) VALUES " _
                 & "('id');"
    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

*Flights table has only one Integer colum named FlightID

What am i missing here?

Comment: You are trying to insert the text 'id' into an integer column.

Comment: Are `Flight` and `ID` fields in a table or variables in your code?

Comment: id is an integer variable im trying to insert its value in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'id' should be a integer variable and not the string 'id'. The correct SQL statement is listed below.

```
dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
          & "(FlightID) VALUES " _
          & "(" & CStr(id) & ");"
```

Comment: Feeling stupid means you really understand and is actually a good thing. Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Bouke. I have a problem with understanding the syntax..
How would the last statement change if i want to add an additional  string variable holding a name to this INSERT?

Comment: Than it would be something like this:

dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
          & "(FlightID, FlightName) VALUES " _
          & "(" & CStr(id) & ",'" & FlightNameVariable & "');"

Note that FlightNameVariable  should be surrounded by single quotes, because it's a string value.

Basic SQL syntax is as follows:

INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2) VALUES (ValueColumn1, ValueColumn2)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like below :

```
Private Sub MainSaveBtn_Click()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim id As Integer

    id = 20
    Debug.Print id
    dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
                 & "(FlightID) VALUES " _
                 & "(" & CStr(id) & ");"
    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

Also the one worked for you is not fully correct! It should be without the single quotation as the column type is `Integer` like below :

```
 dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO Flights " _
                 & "(FlightID) VALUES " _
                 & "(2);"
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are trying to insert "id" in the database. Try to concat your id in the String with the "+" symbol. Or just use a prepared statement to inject your variables in